# Permission denied in rc.local

Tags: 14.04, scripts, services

Here's the contents of my /etc/rc.local

```
/etc/pm/power.d/99macbookair6 true
echo 0 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/iso_layout 
exit 0
```

running 
`service rc.local start`
returns

```
/etc/rc.local: 14: /etc/rc.local: /etc/pm/power.d/99macbookair6: Permission denied
```

Comment: You need to run it with `sudo`.

Comment: Thanks. However, it still doesn't run correctly on startup. Edit: Nevermind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The portion of the error message you want to look at is:

```
/etc/pm/power.d/99macbookair6: Permission denied
```

which says you do not have sufficient permission to execute `/etc/pm/power.d/99macbookair6`.

Even if you have some command here executable by you, you would still get permission denied error for:

```
echo 0 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/iso_layout
```

---

In a nutshell, you can do:

```
service rc.local start
```

only when you have all entries in `/etc/rc.local` executable by you (and also `rc.local` must be readable by you obviously). Same goes for brothers of `start` i.e. `stop`, `restart` etc.

---

To get your current setup working, the most sane way is to run the command as `root`:

```
sudo service rc.local start
```

Comment: I did chmod 777 /etc/pm/power.d/99macbookair6

Answer (score 0):

The "Permission denied" message tells you that you lack sufficient privileges to execute the command. You need to run `service rc.local start` with `sudo` privileges:

```
sudo service rc.local start
```